# Can't connect MIDI Keyboard to Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, midi

I'm trying to connect my Midi Keyboard, which works perfectly fine in Windows, to my RPI 3B+ running Raspbian. I'm connecting using the USB output of the keyboard.

When running dmesg I get this:

```
[  +0,054963] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[  +0,099959] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[  +5,100007] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[  +0,000074] usb 1-1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

After researching a bit, the **-110** error is somehow related with lack of power in the USB ports to support the device, but this keyboard has its own power supply!

I've tried so many things: all USB ports, connecting before booting, switching between self-powered to usb-powered in the keyboard, disabling lpm_enable in boot cmdline, enabling host_support_fs_ls_low_power in boot cmdline, ... Nothing works, I've had this keyboard for months now and can't use it on my RPI.

Help! **Any** hint would be very helpful.

Comment: I would power the keyboard directly from a wall wart and add max_usb_current=1 to config.txt and do a reboot of the Pi.  Let us know if that helps.  Do you have anything else like a keyboard / mouse in the USB ports? edit: Also what power supply are you using for the 3B+ as they are power hungry boards?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. max_usb_current is already default 1 in RPI because I used NOOBS. The keyboard is pluged to the wall outlet, and the RPI is using the original power supply. I have nothing else in the USB ports, I'm controling via ssh.

Comment: `-110` actually means that the device did no answer on time, which can have many reasons. If the keyboard has its own supply, lack of power can be ruled out. Often it's flaky hardware; are you using different cables? Do other devices work on that port?

Comment: Yes, other devices work on the RPi USB (mouse, for instance). The keyboard also works fine in windows, consistently. I always use the same USB cable to connect the keyboard to both RPi and the computer.